# Registering UWP (WinJS) app to receive DEV center notifications

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am facaing a problem with registering my application to receive notifications from dev center.

I was following this tutorial to configure the app ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows/uwp/monetize/configure-your-app-to-receive-dev-center-notifications)) and this is my JS (WinJS app) code that I have:

`Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement.StoreServicesEngagementManager.getDefault().registerNotificationChannelAsync();`

I am calling that on "activated" event of "WinJS.Application".

When I console log the response, I receive the channel URI so I thought that its correct, but when I open DEV center and create new "Ask for rating" notification, I get this message:
**"You must configure your app to receive notifications using the Microsoft Store Services SDK."**

Application is signed, in store, but it is still not working.

Please, could anyone help me with that? What I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: How do you build the channel between your app and Dev Center? What's your OS version and the Store SDK version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test below code and it works without the warning in Dev Center.

```
public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

        RegisterEngagementNotification();

    }

    private async void RegisterEngagementNotification()
    {
        StoreServicesEngagementManager engagementManager = StoreServicesEngagementManager.GetDefault();
        await engagementManager.RegisterNotificationChannelAsync();
    }
```

You need to associate your project with the app name in Dev Center and run your code. Then go back to Dev Center and create the notification.

**Update**:

I also test the code in the video you provide, which works well:

```
   app.onactivated = function (args)
{
    notification.StoreServicesEngagementManager.getDefault().registerNotificationChannelAsync();

}
```

Just make sure you associate your project with the app name in the Store and run it to build the channel.

[image]

Comment: That part of code in my question is the only code I use to init the communication between the app and DEV Center. I was also watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRzDUgkzbtY tutorial where is the same code that I have, but for me it's not working. Your code looks like C# lang, but I use JS in my application (WinJS to be specific)

Comment: @JakubVaněk  please check my updated answer. I also test the sample code in the video you provide, which works well.

Comment: Oh wow, it suddenly started to work (I haven't touched the code and app for about 1 month), maybe Microsoft is watching us :P Anyways.. Thank you for your help :)